# redirecting output of awk script to a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have created an awk script. I want to save its output in a file. But

```
awk -f a.awk >meta.txt
```

is not working. can someone tell me why is this happening?
Can anyone suggest which command is best for creating a file with a particular format. Is it OK if I use awk for this purpose.

Comment: Paste your code here. What is output when you run "awk -f a.awk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the AWK script is not processing a file or receiving input from a pipe, then the whole script should be in the `BEGIN` block.

```
BEGIN { print "foo"
        print "bar"
        while (a < c) a+=b
        print a, b, c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you giving awk any input?  If it sits there doing nothing and you press ^D and it ends you didn't give it anything on STDIN.  What does your a.awk script look like?

Try:

```
cat input.txt | awk -f a.awk > meta.txt
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. AWK accepts input filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

awk needs input. Pipe some data through the command, e.g:

```
ls -l | awk -f a.awk > meta.txt
```

Or:

```
awk -f a.awk -- somefile.with.input > meta.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

when you call an awk script using `-f` , make sure you include the file name to process. Its common mistake to leave it out

```
awk -f a.awk [filename] > output.txt
```

or if your awk script is designed to take in stdin, make sure you are correctly piping stdin to it. eg

```
some command | awk -f a.awk
```

Comment: actually I am using it in another script and all the input is provided by that script so there is no input file

Comment: I want to use this awk script at a particular location in the script, so it is a part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
script -a -c "awk -f a.awk" meta.txt
```

Comment: Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal. But you have already figured out where your mistake was.